# Why it is called "homesick" instead of "parents sick"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, compounds

If a kid went to school he\she cries because he\she is going away from his\her parents not because he\she is going away from his\her home.

So why is it called "homesick" instead of "parents sick" ?

Comment: If you said you were "parent sick" (not ***parents** sick*, just as we don't say ***homes-sick***) that would probably be understood as meaning you were sick ***of*** your parent(s), and wanted to get ***away*** from them.

Comment: What about your brothers and sisters?

Comment: I have a friend whose parents died a long time ago. He was recently on an extended trip abroad (to Singapore, he lives in Texas). He told me he's *homesick*. Would you like to tell him he's using the word incorrectly?

Comment: Please check a few more dictionaries - your understanding of the meaning of 'homesick' is very incomplete.

Answer (score 11):

We don't use "homesick" for a child crying on the first day of school. When people are homesick, it actually *is* from missing their home. Usually the familiarity of it, the ability to be oneself there, the feeling of safety (either physical, mental, or emotional),  or the culture of the area (especially if one is in another country).

If we simply used homesick to describe missing your parents then orphans, the elderly, and those not living with their parents could never be homesick, and obviously they can be.

Comment: Also saying *parents sick* sounds like the parents are physically ill. A "home" cannot be ill/sick.

Comment: Haha, right? "Why are you crying, little boy?" "Parents sick."

Comment: @Mari-Lou A home sick also sounds like home is physically ill.

Comment: @Rajesh Homesick is a single word though, unique by definition on its own.

Comment: I don't know about you guys, but I've seen some pretty sick homes in my time. With like, indoor pools and gazebos and whatnot.

Answer (score 6):

The historical reason is given here:

> homesickness (n.) 1756, translating German Heimweh, from Heim "home"
>   (see home (n.)) + Weh "woe, pain;" the compound is from Swiss dialect,
>   expressing a longing for the mountains, and was introduced to other
>   European languages 17c. by Swiss mercenaries.
>
> [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=homesickness&allowed_in_frame=0)

**Answer**

It is that way because it expresses a longing for one's home, not one's parents.